# Vertica HDFS as external table

Tags: hdfs, parquet, vertica

What is the best practice for working with Vertica and Parquet

my application architecture is:
Kafka Topic (Avro Data).
Vertica DB.
Vertica's scheduler consumed the data from Kafka and ingest it into a managed table in Vertica.

let's say I have Vertica's Storage only for one month of data.
As far as I understood I can create an external table on HDFS using parquet and Vertica API enables me to query these tables as well.
What is the best practice for this scenario?  can I add some Vertica scheduler for coping the date from managed tables to external tables (as parquet).
how do I configure the rolling data in Vertica (dropped 30 days ago every day )
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external tables with Parquet data, whether that data was ever in Vertica or came from some other source.  For Parquet and ORC formats specifically, there are some [extra features](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Tables/ExternalTables/ORC-Parquet.htm), like predicate pushdown and taking advantage of partition columns.

You can [export data in Vertica to Parquet format](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/HadoopIntegrationGuide/NativeFormats/ExportingData.htm).  You can export the results of a query, so you can select only the 30-day-old data.  And despite that section being in the Hadoop section of Vertica's documentation, you can actually write your Parquet files anywhere; you don't need to be running HDFS at all.  It just has to be somewhere that all nodes in your database can reach, because external tables read the data at query time.

I don't know of an in-Vertica way to do scheduled exports, but you could write a script and run it nightly.  You can run a .sql script from the command line using `vsql -f filename.sql`.